# How to insert data rows with Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA script errors when I try to insert data from Sheet1 into Sheet2. Script code delivers only "Case 2-3" ROW numbers, first "Case" does not input into Sheet 2. Wondering what else should be included in VBA script to finalize processes?

*My VBA Script:*

```
Sub CopyFromSheet1()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row ' Last Cell of Column F

  Select Case CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value) ' Looks at the Value in Column C

    Case "Due From"
        Sheet2.Cells(22, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    Case "TOTAL1"
        Sheet2.Cells(23, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    Case "TOTAL2"
        Sheet2.Cells(24, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value

    End Select


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `Select Case CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value)`?

Comment: Remove the line `Select Case CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value)` and `Case Else` and one `End Select` I see no use of it...

Comment: Also what are you overwriting the values of row 22,23,24 of sheet2? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Did you already check to see if `Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value` is really ever equal to `"Due From"`? It could be that you've got an extra space in your original sheet, or a difference in capitalization.

Comment: I will need to look at the Value in Column "C" and "D" from Sheet1.

Comment: @ Mathieu Guindon, Siddharth Rout     In other words, if I select case from column C (i, 3) I also need to select case cells from (i, 4).

Comment: @Robert-Macro, right now you aren't testing CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value) against any cases at all, you're just falling through the "Else" into your next Select Case statement.

Comment: @ Ryan B. if you look at the VBA script I have set it back to original code format. How would I be able to perform the following, if possible.   Select Case CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 3,4).Value) ' Looks at the Value in Column C, D

Comment: So... the 3 cases:  "Due From", "Total1", "Total2" -- are you sometimes finding these values in Column C and sometimes finding them in Column D -- and so wanting to execute your copy to Sheet 2 in either of those situations?

Comment: @ Ryan B.  "Due From" is set in column "D",   "Total1", "Total2"  on Column "C".

Comment: OK!  now we're getting somewhere.  And if "Due From" is in D, is there anything in C?   Or, if Total1/Total2 are in C, is there anything in D?

Comment: Yes, D has Description, where as C has account numbers with Totals in merged cells, these cell are not able to get unmerged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:  Do you everything your doing, but just for Column C.  And then Do it all again for column D?

```
Sub CopyFromSheet1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim col as Long

    for col = 3 to 4
        For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row ' Last Cell of Column F

            Select Case CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, col).Value) 

                Case "Due From"
                    Sheet2.Cells(22, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
                Case "TOTAL1"
                    Sheet2.Cells(23, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
                Case "TOTAL2"
                    Sheet2.Cells(24, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value

            End Select


        Next i

    next col
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ryan.B, I get a Compile error: Variable not defined

Comment: added "Dim col as Long"

Comment: you are welcome.  Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: @Ryan.B,   Question for you.  Sheet 1&2 name titles need to be changed with the following titles:  Sheet1= PrePaidReport,   Sheet2 = NewFormat, after I made the changes, titles change to capital letters, the following "Compile error" displays, "Variable not defined".

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-to-referencing-excel-worksheet-tabs

Comment: @Ryan.B,  Thanks again, all worked okay after I added:  Dim sht As Worksheet